# For loop not creating Div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to create multiple divs on the fly by using a for loop. This code does not give any results. My expectation is for it to create separate divs with the id a1,a2,a3, etc. Can anyone explain why it doesn't? I understand there are other solutions to this on SO, but this is a learning experience for me and I want to know why my solution does not work.

```
function createDiv(divid,divcontent){
  this.div = document.createElement("div");
  this.div.setAttribute("id",divid);
  this.div.innerHTML = divcontent;
}

var keys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
for (i=0; i<keys.length;i++){
    createDiv("a"+i,i);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want to prefix your function vars with `this`. In the function context, `this` in the `window` object

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you are suggesting to use var in the function context and this in the class/object context, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to append the node to a parent - existing - node in the document to make it appear. Like this:

```
function createDiv(divid,divcontent){
  this.div = document.createElement("div");
  this.div.setAttribute("id",divid);
  this.div.innerHTML = divcontent;

  var parent = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  parent.appendChild(this.div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your `div` to an existing html element.

```
document.getElementById("yourHtmlElementId").appendChild(this.div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function only creates the `div` you have to add it to the DOM

```
function createDiv(divid,divcontent){
  this.div = document.createElement("div");
  this.div.setAttribute("id",divid);
  this.div.innerHTML = divcontent;
}

var keys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
for (i=0; i<keys.length;i++){
    var newDiv = createDiv("a"+i,i); //Store the div you just created here
    document.getElementById('yourdivcontainer').appendChild(newDiv); //And add it to the DOM
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function createDiv(id, content){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute("id",id);
  div.innerHTML = content;
  return div;
}
var $parent = $('#parentDiv'); // get parent div
$parent.append(createDiv("a"+i,i));
```

Comment: $ is function, return the element you need, so we should store the element to a temp object.